# How do I mount volumes on a docker container that is being created by another docker container?

Tags: docker, yaml, containers, volumes

I have a containerized REST API server using docker. I have mounted a folder on my host machine to this rest container using docker flag 
`--mount type=bind, source=<path/on/hostmachine>, target=<path/on/container>`

This works perfectly and I can see real time mapping of files between my host and rest container. Now, my rest container generates a yaml file that contains the configuration for the new container that comes up and writes this configuration file to the shared volume mount.

I want to mount the same `<path/on/hostmachine>` that contains the configuration files generated by the rest container to the new container that comes up. The issue is, I do not bring the container up using the cli.

This is why I cannot use the `--mount` flag. I tried multiple ways to try doing it through the yaml file.

> Blockquote
>    - Using absolute path as 
>    `volumes: 
>            - <absolute/path/on/hostmachine>:<path/on/new/container>`

did not work.

> Blockquote
>    - Using volumes with type defined as 
>     `volumes: 
>         - type: bind
>           source:<absolute/path/on/hostmachine>
>           target:<path/on/new/container>`

did not work and gave volumes should be string error

How do I mount the same home directory to the new container that comes up on the rest container?

Comment: What are you using to bring that second container up?

Comment: a simple yaml file and the command docker-compose -f filename.yaml up -d. I have docker-compose installed on the rest container

Comment: So you're standing up the compose services  from within the first container?

Comment: Assuming it is, shouldn't your `source` path for the volume being mounted to compose services be the path within the first container (i.e. not on the host?)

Comment: What error do you get exactly on first method?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue in the first approach. I was using my path as "./Users/username/Desktop" instead of "/Users/username/Desktop" which was causing the path mismatch. I misunderstood the lack of errors. Rookie Mistake, Mea Culpa.